# Edit latex class setting

Tags: document-classes

I'm currently using the tufte-book class. I want to change the chapter style from [display] to [hang].

But when I found the tufte-common.def file, I could not edit it, any suggestion on how I should do it?

Comment: Don't change `def` file. Did you read the documentation? https://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This naturally depends on what sort of editing you are doing.

In nearly every case it's possible to alter the effect of a class or package without editing the file at all. Having loaded that class or package, just redefine (in your document preamble) as necessary. In other words, you start by over-writing definitions, in your document preamble, as far as you can.

In the case of the `tufte` classes, they use `titlesec` to define the style of headings, so you should quite easily be able to use `titlesec`'s API (if one dare call it that) to make the redefinition you want. For instance, if you copy and then adapt the `tufte` definition, you might have something like:

```
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}%
  [hang]% CHANGED shape
  {\relax\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}}% format applied to label+text
  {\itshape\huge\thechapter}% label
  {1em}% CHANGED horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}% before the title body
  [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]% after the title body
\makeatother
```

So, to be clear, that would just go in your preamble after loading the class as usual, and before `\begin{document}`.

You will also need to `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` since by default this class does not use chapter numbers (so there is nothing to hang anyway!). Note that I have put this in `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` guards so I can just use the definition from the class file, which includes ampersand-protected commands. I don't actually know whether that is needed given your redefinition; but it's harmless.

That's how you would modify the definition for a single document. If you want to make more long-term changes, you can do it in one of two ways (other than copy and paste):

1. Define a file `tufte-common-local.tex`. If the Tufte class can find this in the TeX path it will load this. So you can put redefinitions there and save it in a local TeX tree or in the directory you have your source file in, and it will be loaded every time. This is specific to that class.
2. Define a personal style file, e.g. `my-tufte.sty`, put **that** in your TeX path, and load that in any document you need it in. This is a general mechanism.

What you do **not** do is modify `tufte-common.def`. Basically, just don't modify a distributed file (unless you are its maintainer). You very rarely need to modify a file; if you do: copy it with a new name, modify it, put it in your own TeX path (not in the main tree), and load it by its new name.